# Ratingbar layout_centerVertical property not work after set progressDrawable

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am creating custom RatingBar using this property `android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratingstars"`

When I apply this property,  it automatically add some more space. So, I want to remove unnecessary space.

if I remove this property, I got the default RatingBar, so please, help me.

Here is the screenshot, so you can understand better.

[image]

Here is my xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:background="@drawable/placeholder"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rating"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Rides"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/rating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_more"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tv_more"
                android:isIndicator="true"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratingstars"
                android:rating="4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_more"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="More"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Custom drawable **ratingstars.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_blank" />
    <item
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_blank" />
    <item
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_fill" />
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Rating bar lib to customize all the ratingbar properties https://github.com/whinc/RatingBar

Comment: so need to use lib for that??

Comment: as your option,If use lib we can customize everything from rating bar,Normal rating bar act based on style

Comment: Otherwise  you can increase rating bar filled and unfilled icons

Comment: in this library  can i add two drawable with fill and without fill??

Comment: Use thi lib they are provide fill and unfill option,you no need drawable just use icons,https://github.com/whinc/RatingBar

Comment: app:rb_empty="@mipmap/ic_un_fill"
                                app:rb_fill="@mipmap/ic_fill"
                                app:rb_max_count="5"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128419/discussion-between-vadivel-and-arpit-patel).